# how to centre li.(name) in custom.css - dreamweaver

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I'm making an application using Dreamweaver for a school project, and have used a version of the code I found online and re-writing it to suit the assignment needs.

**Problem** I have my links as actual images created in Photoshop (which are working). These are on a .css file, each by their own separate li tag. (These don't need to be changed!)

Eg.

```
li.accom {
    height:93px;
    width:556px;
    background-image:url(../images/accom.png);
}
```

**Question**

How do you center these images? I've tried text-align=centre; and that hasn't worked.

Comment: background: transparent url(../images/accom.png) no-repeat center center /contain;

Answer (score 2):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/64/

**CSS**

```
    li {
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
    list-style-type: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    background: url('http://placehold.it/70x50');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For backgrounds you have [These CSS rules](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp).

For your image, you will need of `background-position` attribute with value: `center` and, if you don't want it to be repeated, `background-repeat` attribute with value `no-repeat`.